# How to do to get other server request and send it back what that server request

Tags: asp.net

All, please advice me how to do other server request and send it back data to that server.
What is the best way to do this in asp.net 2.0 with c#.net. Thanks and may I get your future answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a [webrequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx) if you want to utilize a web type request.  Raw web requests can be a pain so most people utilize WCF or other type of web services.

Comment: hi rerun Thanks for ur answer. Could u please show me example or link to go and learn for me.